# How to draw brick patterned view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am working with a gridview and I want to style it according to the following pattern in the image.The gridview must be populated dynamically. Is there a way to achieve this in android?

[image]

Comment: could be helpful if you google for tag view

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recycler View for this. Please refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html

and StaggeredGridLayoutManager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: Be careful with link only answers. They can become invalid. By the way: where did you know that the questioner uses android in version 7?

Comment: @reporter  :)  i will be careful... And v7 ....lol ... u need an answer for that?

Comment: Minimum version is 4.4.1. Thanks very much

Comment: @TCA Your posted links points to Android API 22.0.0. According my installed Android Studio it is used in Android 5.1. Yes it was a misunderstanding of mine with '/v7/' in the addresses. :-)

Comment: Cool buddy :)  @reporter